# AIX: piping the application command output to more results in malloc failure in application

Tags: redirect, malloc, pipe, aix

I have a command line application, which executed on shell will list the output reading from the database. And it gets this information in chunks for which memory allocation and free is being done.
When I execute the command (Whose output will span around 6000 pages) it is listing the data correctly.
But (only in AIX) when I issue the 'command | more' after displaying random number of pages, memory allocation in the application that is getting the data in chunks is failing.
(Where as the same command implementation with more is working fine in linux for the same data).
Any idea why in AIX it is failing? Anybody know about the memory allocation criteria in AIX? why piping the output to more command causes memory allocation failure in application?

Comment: Hi nos, Thanks much for reading and posting your opinion. 
1. We have reviewed the code for possible memory leaks, but we din't find any. 2. In linux with the same data it is working fine, Source code is same for both linux and AIX 3. plain command execution is not a problem 4. Only when command is executed with (| more) the malloc failure is observed. Hence I feel it is something to do with memory management in AIX.

Comment: If there is a problem with the application, it should cause malloc failure when command is executed without (| more). But without redirecting the output to 'more command' malloc failures are not observed

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what the failure is.  Are you getting a seg fault or is the call the malloc returning 0 indicating that you are out of memory?

The fault could be in an AIX library but it could just as easily be within your application.

Go here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp (or the page that is appropriate for your level)

Search for "malloc debug".  These facilities are not bleeding edge but they are fairly good and complete.  With some time and care you can track down memory leaks and using memory after it has been freed (which sounds like the case here).

Its also good to review the available APARs for your level looking for matches that sound similar.

There are also 3rd party tools like zero fault http://www.zerofault.com/index.html and Purify (which looks like IBM purchased) http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/unix/sysreq/ to help out.

Good luck